# How to limit inputbox response to specific range

Tags: vba, excel, inputbox

New to the VBA world. A different thread was helpful in creating an `InputBox` and setting a specific range but not quite what I need.

I'm having users enter the row number into an `InputBox` where they'd like to add a row but I want to restrict the value they enter from row 12 (where my data starts) to the row above the total row. How do I reference the total row since it will change as rows are added? and how to make the default the row above the total row? (Currently my total row is row 22)

```
Dim varUserInput As Variant
varUserInput = InputBox("Please enter the row number where you'd like to add a row:", _
"What Row?")
If varUserInput = "" Then Exit Sub
If Not IsNumeric(varUserInput) Or varUserInput < 12 Or 22 < varUserInput 
Then 'If value out of specified range
    varUserInput = 22 'Default value
    MsgBox "You Entered a wrong value, using default", vbOKOnly
End If
```

Comment: Is your total row the last row in the worksheet?

Comment: if there is no data below then you can use  Worksheet.UsedRange.Rows

Comment: Why do you want to offer the user a choice of where to add a row? You should find the last used row and add 1, then put the data on that row. Perhaps you should expand your question to explain more about what you actually want to do. Often, when you're new to VBA (as I once was!) you find yourself trying to make something work - but where there'd actually be a much better solution if you approached the problem a different way. What triggers the sub in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To swap 22 with the value of `lastrow`:

```
Sub Test()

Dim varUserInput As Variant, sht As Worksheet, lastrow As Long

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'specify sheet here
lastrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'referencing column A

varUserInput = InputBox("Please enter the row number where you'd like to add a row:", _
"What Row?")

If varUserInput = "" Then Exit Sub

If Not IsNumeric(varUserInput) Or varUserInput < 12 Or lastrow < varUserInput Then 'If value out of specified range

    varUserInput = lastrow 'Default value
    MsgBox "You Entered a wrong value, using default", vbOKOnly

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the default argument while calling the `InputBox` to the *last row* (or whatever).
 Then change the prompt guiding the users what set of numbers are accepted.
 Something like below:

```
Sub marine()
    Dim varUserInput As Variant
    Dim lr As Long, myprompt As String

    With Sheet1 '/* change to your actual sheet */
        lr = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row '/* checks column A, change to suit*/
        myprompt = "Please enter the row number where you'd like to add a row:"
        Do
            '/* enter your last row as default */
            varUserInput = InputBox(myprompt, "What Row?", lr)
            myprompt = "You entered an invalid row number." & vbNewLine & _
                       "Please enter row number between 12 and " & lr
            If varUserInput = "" Then Exit Do '/* if user cancels */
            If Not IsNumeric(varUserInput) Then
                myprompt = "Invalid entry, numeric value expected." & vbNewLine & _
                           "Please enter numbers between 12 and " & lr & "."
            End If
        Loop Until varUserInput <= lr And varUserInput >= 12
    End With
End Sub
```

I can't quite get what you want done since you said you are allowed to enter values greater than the total rows? Well this will restrict users to add rows within the bounds of your data (row 12 and the last row). If this is not what you need, tweak the condition on the `Loop Until` line to suit your needs. Hope this gets you going.